# log4php logger->setLevel() doesn't work

Tags: php, log4php

Not sure why this very simple thing doesn't work -

```
$logger = Logger::getLogger("test");
$logger->setLevel(LoggerLevel::getLevelWarn());

$logger->debug("debug");
$logger->info("info");
$logger->warn("warn");
```

This will print:

```
DEBUG - debug
INFO - info
WARN - warn
```

I must be doing something obviously stupid!  I would assume that neither the debug nor info logging would come through with the setLevel() to warn was present.

Thoughts?

I would like to have multiple loggers that each log at different levels.  Not sure why this is so hard...

Comment: sorry, i should have been more specific.  I want this to go to stdout, my concern is that it is ignoring the setLevel() request and printing debug() and info() level logging even though the level is set to Warn.

Answer (score 3):

If you check the created `Logger` object (after you initialize it with `Logger::getLogger("test");`), you'll see that it already has a parent Logger,  `object(LoggerRoot)`. This object has its level set to `DEBUG`, and that's actually the logger that prints the `debug` and `info` messages.

One possible approach is to use a RootLogger instead:

```
$logger = Logger::getRootLogger();
$logger->setLevel(LoggerLevel::getLevelWarn());

$logger->debug("debug");
$logger->info("info");
$logger->warn("warn");
```

Another approach is to configure rootLogger so that it will log only messages of some very high level (`FATAL`), and let your loggers to set levels appropriate to them. But in that case you need to add your own appenders to those (it's appenders that do the logging job; loggers just manage them). Again, one possible approach:

```
$rootLogger = Logger::getRootLogger();
$rootLogger->setLevel(LoggerLevel::getLevelFatal());

$logger = Logger::getLogger('some');
$logger->addAppender($rootLogger->getAppender('default'));
$logger->setLevel(LoggerLevel::getLevelInfo());

$logger->debug('debug');   // won't print
$logger->info('info');     // will be printed
$logger->warn('warn');     // will be printed too

$logger->fatal('fatal dup');   // will be printed TWICE: 
                               // with $logger, then with $rootLogger

$logger->setAdditivity(false); // switching off log event propagation
$logger->fatal('fatal once');  // will be printed ONCE
```

But it you actually need a complex hierarchy of loggers, I'd highly suggest configuring them all at once, following the approach described in [this section](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/configuration.html) of log4php documentation.

Comment: This doesn't work (excuse the formatting) -- Logger::getRootLogger()->setLevel(LoggerLevel::getLevelFatal());

    $logger = Logger::getLogger("test");
    $logger->setLevel(LoggerLevel::getLevelInfo());

    $logger->debug("debug");
    $logger->info("info");
    $logger->warn("warn");

Comment: Updated my example. Actually, in your case it might make sense to use `Logger::configure` method to set-up all the logs simultaneously.